# Can I use my personal (local) account to authenticate into Azure B2C React MSAL app?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-b2c, msal-react

I'm trying to use React and Azure B2C to sign-up a local account (using personal emails).
I'm able to sign-up and login using userflows, however, I cannot get active account information from MsGraph API.

> `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me 401 (Unauthorized)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,azure AD b2c supports authentication for personal accounts,

1.

> Microsoft Graph supports optional query parameters that you can use to
> specify and control the amount of data returned in a response. The
> support for the exact query parameters **varies** from one API
> operation to another, and depending on the API, can differ between the
> **v1.0** and **beta** endpoints.

[Use query parameters to customize responses - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters)

Try with GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/
You can use use $select to control the properties returned,
Ex: /me?$select=displayName,jobTitle

2.
Do make sure to give required claims marked in application claims.

[image]

If you want to acquire a token for all the static scopes of a v1.0 application, append ".default" to the app ID URI of the API: app ID/.default

Calling the /me endpoint requires a signed-in user and therefore a delegated permission. Application permissions are not supported when using the /me endpoint.

[Article](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/working-with-b2c.md) says

> Users cannot obtain tokens for Microsoft APIs (e.g. MS Graph API)
> using delegated permissions. Applications can obtain tokens for
> Microsoft APIs using application permissions (user management
> scenarios).

Reference:
[microsoft-graph-operations#user-flow-authentication-methods-beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations#user-flow-authentication-methods-beta)